# Let $f:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$, if $f$ is a linear transformation, prove that $Df(a)=f$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, manifolds

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$, if $f$ is a linear transformation, prove that $Df(a)=f$.

My try :

By definition of derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ ,  ***If***  I know that there exists some linear transformation $\lambda: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ such that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\left\|f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda(h)\right\|}{\left\|h\right\|}=0 \tag{$*$}$$ in other words, if I know that $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then I can conclude that  $\lambda=Df(a)$.

If I know that $(*)$ holds,$$(*) \Rightarrow  \lim_{h \to 0} \left\| f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda(h)\right|=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{h \to 0} \left\| f(a)+f(h)-f(a)-\lambda(h)\right\|=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{h \to 0} \left\| f(h)-\lambda(h)\right\|=0$$Therefore $Df(a)=f$.

I think that something is wrong with my approach, I already appreciate your hints/ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try putting $\lambda = f$ in your *, and then using linearity.

Comment: Thanks ! $f$ itself works, since it is a LT.